# User timezone issues

Tags: ios, swift, timezone, gregorian-calendar, nstimezone

My app was working fine until the changing of the clocks this morning. I set the user's timezone using the following code.

```
let usersTimeZone: String = ltzAbbrev()
var gregorian: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSISO8601Calendar)!
gregorian.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: usersTimeZone)!
```

The code worked above until the clocks went forward this morning and now `ltzAbbrev()` is returning `GMT+1` and this is causing my program to crash with the standard error

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are using the function

```
func ltzAbbrev() -> String { return NSTimeZone.localTimeZone().abbreviation! }
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/27053592/1187415. So with

```
let usersTimeZone:String = ltzAbbrev()
gregorian.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: usersTimeZone)!
```

you are doing two conversions

```
time zone -> abbreviation -> time zone
```

and that does not work reliably, as stated in the `NSTimeZone`
documentation:

> In general, you are discouraged from using abbreviations except for
>   unique instances such as “UTC” or “GMT”. Time Zone abbreviations are
>   not standardized and so a given abbreviation may have multiple
>   meanings—for example, “EST” refers to Eastern Time in both the United
>   States and Australia

It is also not necessary, since you can simply set

```
gregorian.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
```

instead.

Another (unrelated) problem *might* be the usage of `NSISO8601Calendar`,
as the `NSLocale` documentation states

> Identifier for the ISO8601. The ISO8601 calendar is not yet implemented.

The Gregorian calendar is obtained with

```
let gregorian = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
```