# How to find midnight for a given Date in Swift

Tags: swift, date, nsdate

I creating an itinerary generation app where the user is required to enter the dates of his/her trip. The only problem is, using UIDatePicker the dates are always given as the current time for a given day/month/year.

In a separate file I've extended Date class to try and write a simple method that will return midnight for a given date.

First I tried

```
    var midnight:Date{
    let cal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    return cal.startOfDay(for: self)
}
```

However this always gave me either 04:00 or 05:00 depending on daylights savings, which gave me the idea that I should simply remove 4 or 5 hours depending on daylight savings, and so I created the following methods:

```
    var timezone:TimeZone{
    return TimeZone.current
}
///Returns the first instance of the date, e.g. 2018-02-26 00:00:00
var trueMidnight:Date{
    let cal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let midnight = cal.startOfDay(for: self)
    let secondsFromGMT = TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT()
    print("Daylight savings? \(daylightSavings)")
    return midnight.addingTimeInterval(Double(secondsFromGMT))
}
///If this var returns true, then daylight savings time is active and an hour of daylight is gained (during the summer).
var isDaylightSavings:Bool{
    return timezone.daylightSavingTimeOffset(for: self) == 0 ? false : true
}
var daylightSavings:Double{
    return isDaylightSavings ? 3600.0 : 0.0
}
```

However these methods sometimes return midnight, 23:00, or even 22:00 the previous day.

I'm a relatively inexperienced programmer so I feel like I'm lacking a basic understanding for the date class or missing a large concept. Why is it so difficult for me to simply find midnight on a given date?

I even forsook the idea of returning midnight and tried to just find noon on a given day with the code:

```
    var noon:Date{
    let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    var components = gregorian.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: self)

    components.hour = 12
    components.minute = 0
    components.second = 0
    return gregorian.date(from: components)!
}
```

But this returns 16:00 or 17:00 as opposed to noon. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you need startOfDay local time or UTC midnight?

Comment: Does true midnight means UTC 12am ? if so it would be much easier to simply change your calendar timezone to UTC

Comment: I'm not sure, but in the future I'd eventually like to be able to export the itinerary using EventKit, so local time?

Comment: this will depend on your goal. Generally you just save the date using UTC timezone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016578/swift-how-to-create-a-date-time-stamp-and-format-as-iso-8601-rfc-3339-utc-tim/28016692#28016692

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053135/how-to-get-a-users-time-zone/27053592?s=2|44.2602#27053592

Comment: FYI - the 1st bit of code in your question is just fine. It is giving you midnight (local time). Why do you think otherwise? Is it because you print the resulting Date and doing so happens to show you that date in UTC? That doesn't make your date wrong, it simply means you are misunderstanding the output of printing a `Date` instance.

Comment: Don't print the date print its description using current timezone `print(Date().description(with: .current))`

Comment: Thanks guys, I guess that was what I was misunderstanding.

Comment: Please delete the question. Failing to understand the output when printing a date is very common and has been discussed here MANY times.

Comment: This questions is marked as duplicating two others. However, one of those two does not involve Swift and the other has -2 upvotes.

Comment: @LeoDabus but the description prints an ugly Wednesday, March 1, 2023 at 12:00:00 AM ... so if it's a date object, the time will always be 16:00 ? it is impossible to get a date object with 00:00 as time?

Comment: @chitgoks Under the hood the date object stores the amount of seconds since a reference date (UTC). When you print a date object it will always show the UTC time description. It you need another locale description you can use `date.description(with: .current)` to display the timezone of your current locale. You can also pass another locale(fixed) if you need.

Comment: @chitgoks if you need to display the date to the user you should use DateFormatter date and time style. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28347285/2303865)

Comment: @LeoDabus i resolved it. added an extension to get the local date by converting utc timezone to user's current timezone

Comment: Don’t do that a date does not have a timezone. Only it description does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you print a date, it is **printed in UTC** time. So when you print your `Date`s, they differ from your local time by 4/5 hours.

If you use the following code instead

```
print(yourDate.description(with: .current))
```

Where `yourDate` is your date, it will be in the correct time zone.

Comment: I didn't know about the `Date` method `description(with:)` Thanks for that. (voted)

Comment: It seems to use a very verbose format though. I prefer `DateFormatter.localizedString(from:dateStyle:timeStyle)`, or better yet, the extension I provided, since it lets you control the output format.

Answer (score 4):

You're confused.

If you use

```
print(Date())
```

You will get a date in UTC. If you're in the UTC+5 time zone, that date will be 5 hours greater than your local time. Thus if you try to display midnight local time in UTC, it will show up as 5:00 AM in UTC.

Try this:

```
extension Date {
    func localString(dateStyle: DateFormatter.Style = .medium, 
      timeStyle: DateFormatter.Style = .medium) -> String {
        return DateFormatter.localizedString(
          from: self, 
          dateStyle: dateStyle, 
          timeStyle: timeStyle)
    }

    var midnight:Date{
        let cal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        return cal.startOfDay(for: self)
    }
}
print("Tonight at midnight is " + Date().midnight.localString())
```

That code uses a function `localString()` that takes advantage of a DateFormatter method `localizedString(from:dateStyle:timeStyle:)` that converts a `Date` to a string in the current locale (which includes the local time zone.

I suggest adding that extension to your apps.

Comment: Note that not every date starts at midnight. It might return 1am or 2am as well