# Current Location TimeZone abbrevation

Tags: ios, swift, timezone

I want to show timezone as "IST", "EST", etc.
That seems to be simple but there is an issue.When I use following code:

```
let timeZone = TimeZone.current.abbreviation()
```

For India I get "GMT+5:30" but for Toronto, I get "EDT".
Please help, or let me know some other way to show such abbreviations.

**EDIT 1**

I came up with a workaround but still, sometimes I get some weird timezones:

```
func getTimeZoneAbbrevation() -> String {
    var returnTimeZone = ""
    let timezone = TimeZone.current.identifier
    let dict = TimeZone.abbreviationDictionary
    for (key,value) in dict {
        if value == timezone {
            returnTimeZone = key
            break
        }
    }
    if returnTimeZone == "" {
            if let timezone = NSTimeZone.default.abbreviation() {
                returnTimeZone = timezone
        }
    }
    return returnTimeZone
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
[image: Playground code using kamaldeep's solution]

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053135/how-to-get-a-users-time-zone

Comment: @kamaldeepsinghbhatia yes, I have already checked it, check my edit 1, I have implemented that code in my function, but the issue with that is, for Toronto it returns me "America/Toronto", which is not present in the abbreviationDictionary.

Comment: Note that you *should* be getting `"EDT"` for Toronto right now, because that is the *current* time zone abbreviation.  They are currently in Eastern Daylight Time.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
let someTime = TimeZone(identifier: "America/Toronto")
let timezone = someTime?.abbreviation()
```

Now `timezone` contains value `"EDT"` so you can directly use this.

Just FYI if you want to check for these identifier so you can get it from

```
var timeZoneIdentifiers: [String] { return TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers }
```

I hope this will help now.

Comment: What are you getting on Toronto? Is it "EDT"? and what you want at that place?

Comment: I think you should check the list because there is no place for Toronto... So possibly you can check alternative location. As for India there is only "Asia/Kolkata"... Just find a city which is in same timezone.

Comment: can you tell me how can I achieve that,  find a city which is in same timezone

Comment: @cs832 see my edit I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: For more details just see this answer. It is really awesome https://stackoverflow.com/a/27053592/5622566

Comment: yes, my solution is inspired by the StackOverflow link you provided, also the solution you provided workes for Toronto but for India it gives "GMT+5:30", what I am planning is adding timezones manually to the dictionary apple provides.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> let timeZoneDict = TimeZone.abbreviationDictionary.filter {
>   $0.value == TimeZone.current.identifier
>   }
>   if !timeZoneDict.isEmpty {
>   let timeZone = timeZoneDict.first?.key
>   print(timeZone)
>   }

Comment: doesn't work for Toronto. The timeZoneDict is empty.