# Swift iOS TimeZone as String?

Tags: ios, swift, timezone

How do I get a String, "Pacific/Auckland" for example, from a user's TimeZone?

I can get the "NZST" abbreviation with

```
TimeZone.current.abbreviation()
```

But it's the full name I need, if I can get it.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `TimeZone`? There's a pretty obvious property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of these should work for you.

```
timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EST")
print(timeZone) // "some(America/New_York (current))\n"
print(timeZone.abbreviation()) // "Optional("EDT")\n"
print(timeZone.description) // "America/New_York (current)\n"
print(timeZone.identifier) // "America/New_York\n"
```

I believe you are looking for the last one.

Comment: What's the point of the `DateFormatter` here? All you need is the `TimeZone`. And the question is asking about the users's current timezone.

Comment: Thats true it just happened to be there in my playground. I will remove it.

Answer (score 3):

```
let timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "NZST")
let identifier = timeZone?.identifier
```

This is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing...

```
TimeZone.current.localizedName(for: .standard, locale: Locale.current)
```

In the first parameter, you can select different name styles. The only two I've tried out are .generic and .standard.

I found the answer here: [How to get a user's time zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053135/how-to-get-a-users-time-zone)

I hope that helps.

Comment: This is not the requested result.

Comment: My bad. For HenryRootTwo's "NZST", the result would have been "New Zealand Standard Time" instead of "Pacific/Auckland". I like how you used the identifier property, but I think he needs TimeZone.current.identifier, because in his original code he's trying to retrieve not a specific time zone, but whatever is the user's time zone.