# How to convert timezone format in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, timezone

I got timezone format like this  GMT+5:30.

```
TimeZone.current.abbreviation(), this will return string value like: //GMT+5:30
```

But I need to convert the above format to  **Asia/Kolkata**

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you look at the other properties of `TimeZone`?

Comment: Duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053135/how-to-get-a-users-time-zone/27053592

Comment: Yes, TimeZone.current.identifier  return like  'Asia/Kolkata'. But I need to convert GMT+5:30 to Asia/Kolkata

Comment: In what form do you have `GMT+5:30`? Is that a `String`? A `TimeZone`? What? [Edit] your question with details.

Comment: How could a bot tell that the time zone of Asia/Kolkata is the only one with GMT+5:30?

Comment: Your edit means you already have a specific `TimeZone` instance. Since you want the identifier and not the abbreviation, simply call `identifier` instead of `abbreviation()`.

Comment: i got timezone as IST insted of GMT +5:30 in mobile but in simulator i got GMT+5:30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling:

```
TimeZone.current.abbreviation()
```

call:

```
TimeZone.current.identifier
```

In your case you will get `Asia/Kolkata` instead of `GMT+5:30`.

But let's assume you only have a string with a timezone abbreviation such as `"GMT+5:30"`. You can't easily convert that to a specific timezone identifier because there can be more than one timezone at a given time offset.

Here's a little function that creates a timezone from the abbreviation string and then finds all matching timezone identifiers that have the same offset.

```
func matchingTimeZones(abbreviation: String) -> [TimeZone]? {
    if let tz = TimeZone(abbreviation: tzstr) {
        return TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers.compactMap { TimeZone(identifier: $0) }.filter { $0.secondsFromGMT() == tz.secondsFromGMT() }
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

You can get the matching list for `"GMT+5:30"` with:

```
let matches = matchingTimeZones(abbreviation: "GMT+5:30")
```

If you print that result you will see one of them is `"Asia/Calcutta"` (in an English locale).

Comment: @rmaddy , How can I convert timezone identifier to abbreviation? (For example how can I convert 'Asia/Kolkata' to '+05.30')

Comment: @IKKA Create a `TimeZone` using the `"Asia/Kolkata"` identifier. Then get that time zone's `abbreviation`. That's been covered in other question. Please do some searching if you need further assistance with your new question.