# How to get human friendly current local language name in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

The current language code can be retrieved via `Locale.current.languageCode` but what if I need a more human-friendly name like "English" or "Japanese"?

Does the developer must maintain a mapping in the app or there is a native way to get the language name?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27255138/2303865

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [localizedString(forLocaleIdentifier:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1642864-localizedstring) method on Locale object.

```swift
let locale: Locale = .current
locale.localizedString(forLocaleIdentifier: "pl_PL") // "Polish"
```

along with other useful functions that can help you get localized region or currency names from codes.

```swift
locale.localizedString(forRegionCode: "PL") // "Poland"
locale.localizedString(forCurrencyCode: "PLN") // "Polish Zloty"
```

and to use different locale than the `.current` you can easily initialize it with [one of the available identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/2293697-availableidentifiers).

```
let japanese = Locale(identifier: "ja_JP")
japanese.localizedString(forLocaleIdentifier: "pl_PL") // "ポーランド語"
japanese.localizedString(forRegionCode: "PL") // "ポーランド"
japanese.localizedString(forCurrencyCode: "PLN") // "ポーランド ズウォティ"
```

Comment: The identifier "pl_PL" is not a language code. It's a locale identifier. The "pl" part is the language code and the "PL" part is the region code.

Comment: Thank you @HangarRash for pointing this out, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
Locale.current.localizedString(forLanguageCode: Locale.current.languageCode)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are rarely useful. Explain, as part of your answer, what you think it contributes beyond what the existing, accepted answer provides.

Comment: This is also out-of-date as of iOS 16.